# How do I set a task to done on due date?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, tasks

How do I set a task to done on due date when the user haven't taken any action on that task.

Can I use/create a workflow in SharePoint 2013 designer?

On due date completion the task should set to done and it must proceed with other actions in the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using JQuery.  Look at a previous post I made about updating list information based on date [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/111484/find-interval-between-dates-problem/111503#111503) This block of code in my answer changes a priority indicator field based on date.