# Workflow not behaving correctly

Tags: 2010, workflow, date-time, pause

I have a work flow that fires off email notifications at specific dates, based on the number of days between the `Expiration` date and `Today`. It works up until a user goes to change the date of the list item, and then nothing happens. Here's what I have so far. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Does your workflow start on Item Created and Updated?

Comment: No expert on WFs, but I thought once a WF is fired, the dates are going to stay the same and is not dynamic. If you go in and change the dates, a WF is not going to know it if it is already running.

Comment: @AmalHashim Item Created

Comment: @Paulster2 the user has the ability to change the end date. So basically it notifies them something's expiring, they go in and update the date and everything starts over

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using jQuery to find your date and times for your emails.  This is going to eventually cause a large timer job service load.  From what I can tell your workflow is running for 90+ days.  Just because it is paused, does not mean it is not running on the services in the background.

I have some code which gave [here on another WF question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/111484/find-interval-between-dates-problem/111503#111503) that will eliminate the need for WF pauses and will support your dynamic date needs.  You should use jQuery to track how many days it has been based off of the created date column. No one can screw with it then.  This way too, the workflow will only fire when it needs to instead of being in a paused state for so long.  Just a suggestion hope it helps.  Good luck to ya!